# Download video from the video tag in my phonegap app which has src

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I am adding a download button to download video from my phonegap android app.
How to download the video to my storage of android from the video tag in my app

I have to know the optimized way to complete this feature

```
function videoDownload(){

//find the first element with video tag in current screen
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
//video.src gives url as expected
console.log(video.src);
//show download progress for user
//download video to the storage
const url = video.src
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.style.display = 'none';
a.href = url;
// the filename you want
a.download = 'share-video.mp4';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, SO is not a coding service. Please share the code you have tried to achieve the above, thanks :)

Comment: is it ok. the above code not working. I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first install [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) to get started with your file download. Then you need to call the [download()](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download) of the plugin to download a file. The below is a sample code that can achieve the download, but clearly, you need to provide it with actual URLs for the download to be successful.

```
function downloadAsset() {

  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var assetURL = 'your_video_url'; // is video.src string
  //for android app
  var fileName = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[package-name]/files' + 'new_name'; // is share-video.mp4

  fileTransfer.download(assetURL, fileName,
    function(entry) {
      console.log("Success!");
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("Error");
    });
}
```

Comment: After execution of download it gives success but video not yet dowloaded.url is right.I have tried using share-video and share-video.mp4 as fileame.Not working

Comment: What does your ‘entry’ object say? Can u console that along with your success message please? It should ideally contain something like a nativeURL that will hold the downloaded path.

Comment: filepath  is the error. It is working.Thank you for the answer